# ST_MakeEnvelope vs casting BOX as box2d

Tags: postgis

When I'm filtering by bounding box, I've found that I can either do

```
SELECT id, the_geom 
FROM my_table
WHERE the_geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(minlng,minlat, maxlng,maxlat);
```

as well as

```
SELECT id, the_geom 
FROM my_table
WHERE the_geom && 'BOX(minlng minlat, maxlng maxlat)'::box2d;
```

I believe both queries have a small overhead in converting the given bounding box to a valid geometry but... is there any rational disadvantage on using the second one?

Comment: You forget ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(minlng, minlat), ST_MakePoint(maxlng, maxlat)); :-) which is obviously longer that the first one, but the same idea. Personally, I always prefer functions that work directly on numbers to ones involving text concatenation plus a cast, though in this case, the performance difference is going to be measured in milliseconds, if that.

Answer (score 2):

If you run a billion of them you might see the difference between the overhead of parsing a text box vs directly constructing the geometry from the envelope coordinates. Do whatever you like the most and find the most convenient.